# Two dimensional array (matrix) in python

Tags: python, matrix, indexing

I would like to ask regarding the Two dimensional array in python.
How to access using indexes, to specific element (i,j) of a matrix(2 dimensional array) in python ?

Thanks a lot in advance !

Comment: Please, take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Given a two-dimensional array

```
a = [
   [1, 2, 3],
   [4, 5, 6],
   [7, 8, 9]
]
```

index with row then column, starting at zero

```
a[0][0] = 1
a[0][1] = 2
a[0][2] = 3
a[2][1] = 8
```

Answer (score 0):

Imagine the following array:

```
x= [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

by : `x[0][0]` you get 1 `x[2][2]` you get 9

Arrays are indexed from zero